# Using PHP Check Email ID Already Exist Or Not in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if an email already exist in database and if exists, show message on the screen and don't run the PHPMailer. So I'm using this code below. the email that already exists is not saved in the database as I want, but the PHPMailer still run and the message does not appear.

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
require  'email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = $_POST['emailFor'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE email=?");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
$query = $result->fetch_assoc(); 


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    echo "This email has already been registered";
} else {
    // ==== INSERT VALUES INTO DB 
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO people (email) VALUES (?);");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail ->isSMTP();
```

Comment: You check the number of rows, and either display a message or update the database. The call to PHPMailer runs regardless of the outcome. You probably need an `exit` after you `echo "This email..."`

Comment: Yes, I tried to put an "exit;" or "break;" but the message does not appear and result in an error (HTTP ERROR 500)

Comment: Then you need to look in the server error log to find out what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: By the way, why have you used a prepared statement in your `INSERT` query, but not in your `SELECT` query? `SELECT` is just as vulnerable to SQL injection as any other statement

Comment: I edited and tried to create prepared statements. Can you see if it's right?

Comment: You've used an `i` type, but email will be a string. Use `$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);`

Comment: Not relevant to your issue, but you're using an old and unsupported version of PHPMailer. [Upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way is to create a UNIQUE index on the `email` column, then you could use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of simple insert, and then you could check `affected_rows` to determine if the insertion was successful or the email already exists in the table:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT IGNORE INTO people (email) VALUES (?);");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) === 1) {
    // email was new, here you should send the email
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
}
else {
     echo "This email has already been registered";
}
```